# Is it possible to manage colors of rows in pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, colors, streamlit

I'm currenty in an issue with my python script.

I had generate a transposed dataframe from a groupby aggregates.

I want to color rows 3 by 3 with differents colors, but after few trying, I haven't find my solution.

With a background gradient, I can color all cells with the same color but not the indexes names. Screen just below:

```
cm = sb.light_palette("green", as_cmap=True)
data_filtered = df.groupby(argu).agg(
                {'country_code_count': ['sum'],
                 'age_min': ['min'],
                 'age_max': ['max'],
                 'age_mean': ['mean'],
                 'planned_contract_duration_min': ['min'],
                 'planned_contract_duration_max': ['max'],
                 'planned_contract_duration_mean': ['mean'],
                 'payment_plan_amount_min': ['min'],
                 'payment_plan_amount_max': ['max'],
                 'payment_plan_amount_mean': ['mean'],
                 })
data_filtered.columns = [x[0] for x in data_filtered.columns]
data_filtered = data_filtered.T
data_filtered.columns = ['-'.join(x) for x in data_filtered.columns]
data_filtered = data_filtered.round(1).style\
            .format("{:.11}")\
            .background_gradient(cmap=cm)
```

[image: Here the app]

Thanks for the reading,

Regards

Comment: Where is your datafarme being printed? Jupyter notebook?

Comment: The dataframe is pritned in streamlit

Comment: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/style.html have you seen this documentation? there are several solutions that can help you, for example, slicing part

Comment: ah ok, it might be tricky to do on stremlit, I would consider making the index a column and  then hiding the index. Following https://discuss.streamlit.io/t/using-st-dataframe-with-color-code-style-but-hiding-index/9437